# Task executor will not run next task immediately

Tags: spring-integration

I have below configuration where I am trying to process at most 5 requests concurrently. 
Each request takes much different time to process. What I am noticing it starts processing 5 tasks which is great but when one of the task completes, it does not immediately takes another task, in fact it is waiting for all 5 tasks to complete and then only it starts next 5 tasks.  So I am getting some sort of batch processing behavior. May be I have not configured properly, please help to correct this. I want to start the next task immediately as soon as the thread is done processing one.

I can increase the queue capacity and in that case it does start the next task but I only want to invoke my inbound message provider when I am ready to process the message, not to just hold it in task executor queue.

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="feeder" channel="in">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="100">        
    </int:poller>    
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:bridge input-channel="in" output-channel="out" />

    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1-5" keep-alive="120" 
        queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<int:channel id="out">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>


<int:service-activator input-channel="out" output-channel="replyChannel"
              ref="processor" method="process"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your 'caller runs' policy; this means the polling thread runs one of your tasks (#6) and won't poll again until that task completes.

You really need to use a `CallerBlocks` policy - we [added one to Spring Integration in 3.0.3 and 4.0.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/util/CallerBlocksPolicy.java#L36).

You would need to wire up the TaskExecutor as a `<bean/>`; the namespace doesn't support custom policies.

EDIT:

Created [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3519).

Comment: There is a slight problem though, it polls for next task but holds it until a tread is available, is it possible to make it poll for next after a tread becomes free? I have a priority queue that it is polling so i would like to poll when really ready to execute.

Comment: Not really; you might be able to do something with a custom trigger but I doubt it will completely satisfy your needs.

Comment: However, you could add an `Advice` in the poller's `<advice-chain/>` and don't do the poll if the executor is busy.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810528/ftp-ftps-adapters-custom-trigger-poller) for how to write/configure an advice.