# FTP/FTPS Adapters custom trigger/poller

Tags: spring-integration

First, I have just started looking at Spring Integration today, so I have very little experience.  I already have a basic scheduled ftp file parser setup using spring integration:

```
<int:channel id="ftpIn"  />

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="ftpIn"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    filename-pattern="*.xml"
    local-directory="${TEMP_DIR}">

    <int:poller fixed-rate="${ftp.polling.rate}" />

</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${ftp.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${ftp.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${ftp.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ftp.password}" />
</bean>

<int:service-activator
    input-channel="ftpIn"
    method="handle"
    ref="ftpInHandler" />

<bean id="ftpInHandler" class="thanks.for.looking.FtpInHandler" />
```

This works; however, I want to add additional functionality that checks (at a fixed-rate) if the system is ready before starting the scheduled (fixed-rate) ftp adapter.  I am stuck on the best way to implement this.  Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Best Regards,

Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<poller>` has an option like `<advice-chain>`.

So you just need to write some custom `Advice`:

```
public class CheckSystemInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
          return mySystem.isOK() ? invocation.proceed() : null;
    }

}
```

Configure it as a `<bean>` with your `system checker` and inject it into that `<advice-chain>`.

It will be invoked on each poll.

Comment: Or set `auto-startup="false"` and only start the adapter when you are ready. Alternatively, I generally recommend using the outbound gateway (LS, GET etc) when performing "on demand" type applications with FTP.