# Will Spring Integrations Task Scheduler Block is all threads in Task Executor are busy

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-integration

If all the threads in the taskExecutor are busy (All 100 of them). Will the threads used by the poller block? Or will the poller thread leave the message on the queue and try again in another 300ms?

```
<int:channel id="tasksIn">
    <int:queue capacity="50"/>    
</int:channel>

<int:bridge input-channel="tasksIn" output-channel="taskProcessing" >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="300" max-messages-per-poll="2" />
</int:bridge>

<int:channel id="taskProcessing">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
</int:channel>

<service-activator input-channel="taskProcessing" output-channel="taskCompleteChannel" ref="taskProcessor" method="processTask"/>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="100" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior depends on the `queue-capacity` attribute of the task executor and its rejection policy.

By default the queue is unbounded so the tasks will be queued until you eventually run out of memory.

When there is a bounded queue size and there are no available threads and the queue is full, the default policy is to throw an exception (default reject policy is abort). You can set the rejection policy to `CALLER_RUNS`, in which case the task will run on the poller thread.

Spring Integration provides a `CallerBlocksPolicy` (it needs a queue capacity > 0) but the task namespace doesn't support custom policies, you'll need to define the executor as a `<bean/>`.

For more sophistication, you can apply an [advice to the poller and "skip" polls under your chosen conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796527/task-executor-will-not-run-next-task-immediately/25797448#25797448). As can be seen in that link, we plan to provide a standard advice in the near future.

Comment: Thanks Gary, that clears my understanding up. Does the same behavior apply to task executors defined on the poller? In this case does the poller hand off to the task executer to do the polling? Or does the task executer to the polling?

Comment: The poller is a scheduler thread (from the `taskScheduler` bean). If you don't supply a task executor, we use a `SyncTaskExecutor` so the poll runs directly on the scheduler thread. If you supply a task executor, the poll is handed off to it so to "skip" a poll using an advice you'd need the `CALLER_RUNS` policy.